# Exported a DEM raster from Earth Engine, raster shows up as entirely black with all pixel values as zero in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, dem, nodata, srtm

I used Google Earth Engine to get SRTM Digital Elevation Data Level 4 imagery. I clipped it to the extent of Nepal using a vector I uploaded, then exported the image to my Google Drive. After downloading it and opening it in QGIS, I just see an entirely black raster with min and max values both 0. This despite the layer showing up properly in the Earth Engine window itself, in the map below the code editor.

[image]

[image]

```
var table: Table users/away29394/NPL_adm0
var image2: Image "SRTM Digital Elevation Data Version 4"

var clipped_srtm = image2.clip(table2);
Export.image.toDrive({image: clipped_srtm, description: 'Nepal_SRTM', folder: 'Fevrier_Mars'});
Map.addLayer(clipped_srtm, {min: 0, max: 9000}, "Clipped Nepal SRTM");
```

I tried the same process with a different DEM raster (WWF Hydrosheds). I also tried changing the vector extent. Got the same results both times.

I want to add that I did not specify a NoData value for the export process from Earth Engine.

What could the issue be?

**Edit**: As suggested below, I clipped the exported raster to a mask vector (extent of Nepal, as per DIVA-GIS) in QGIS. Now I am getting a range of values, though only 0 to 6300 (the highest value of Nepal should be 8848).

Also, the raster has lost about 100 times the resolution it should have. This particular SRTM should have a pixel size of 90 m, but after reprojecting the clipped raster to Mercator, the pixel size is showing around 9000 m. This is unusable for my work. I did not explicitly do any compression at any stage. Also, even the unprojected raster has similar-sized grid cells, which is far lower resolution than how it should be, as showed in the Earth Engine map window.

Comment: A link please to your data.

Comment: @Pointdump Do you mean the exported raster? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Grc0fE8WVOBnn8AVB3ADkZ3qT2gPt-No/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add your code as formatted text. The image you provided seems wrong, it covers the entire world.

Comment: Your linked tif is a small, unusable 84KB rectangle. Have you tried to clip the original SRTM data in another program like QGIS?

Comment: @Nikos I have embedded the Earth Engine code in the post above.

Comment: @Pointdump I clipped the output raster by a Nepal mask in QGIS. So now it does show multiple pixel values. Though there are still some issues: the max pixel value is only 6300 even though the highest point, Everest, should be 8848. Also, after reprojecting to Mercator, the raster pixel size in the Layer Properties is '9000,-10232'. This seems to be far too low-res, since the SRTM data I used should have a pixel size of 90 m. I did not do any compression explicitly during the clipping process. Not sure why I lost so much resolution, but I do need it at ~90 m.

Comment: Add scale: 90, and CRS if needed

Comment: @aldo_tapia Hey thanks. I think I got a good idea now. I should have looked at all the arguments of the function I was using! 90 is the native pixel size of the raster, but that ended up being too computationally heavy, so I went with the largest permissible size for my species in question (I'm running a species distribution model). Now the file sizes seem more manageable.

Comment: @AdityaBanerjee it doesn't look like a huge file, although the clipping process is computationally expensive. Download the DEM using the bounding box of your area and then clip it in QGIS

Comment: @aldo_tapia The initial one I had shared had a pixel size of 9000m that one wasnt big. But changing it to 90, the native pixel resolution, did end up causing problems. It was dividing up the export process into multiple rasters. And after clipping, I ended up with our 4 GB files making up all of Nepal.